# Space horror book series. Cryo-sleep spaceship escapes dying Earth but is captured en-route

Tags: story-identification, novel

I've been looking for this book series for a few years. Earth is coming to an end and a select few are selected to go to some distant planet but never make it. Instead, and this is well before they know it, they end up on another much larger spaceship that uses the data from their ship about Earth to create a very weird world using paintings and other data in an attempt to replicate what it thinks their world is like.

Now, I don't remember many specific details, but the biggest one I do remember is that in cryosleep one of women has a baby and this baby is evil and takes control of its mother as a host.

The people go through a bunch of hardships and it's spread through a few books which I never finished so I don't know how it ends, but I would like to finish reading them if possible.

Comment: This question has been closed as a duplicate. This is not an indication that your question is bad, or invalid, but simply a way in which we tie things together in the system so that the details get shared in queries.

Answer (score 5):

After posting this question (and not expecting an answer with such sparse details) I did some digging and found it.

The novel series is called Remnants. The first book in the series is [The Mayflower Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remnants_(novel_series)).

> Remnants is a series of science fiction books written by K. A. Applegate between July 2001 and September 2003. It is the story of what happens to the survivors of a desperate mission to save a handful of human beings after an asteroid collides with the Earth. Eighty people are placed aboard a converted space shuttle using untested "quack" hibernation technology and fired blindly into space hours before all life on Earth is obliterated by a large asteroid called The Rock. They are then picked up by a large, sentient space craft of monumental proportions known as 'Mother' which is inhabited by various races. 'Mother' can manipulate the physical environment within the craft's limits and often does so. Only a few people placed in stasis actually were alive and capable of being reanimated when they reached 'Mother'.

[image: Book cover - *Remnants: The Mayflower Project*]

It's an amazing series and I plan to order it today!

Comment: You will be able to accept your self-answer 48 hours after asking it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons (clicking earlier will indicate how much longer you have to wait).

Comment: Jut mentioning, you probably are at the 48 hour mark now. :)